# project.basedir issue in Maven, jar not referred

Tags: maven, jar, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-dependency

I have jar file in my project home folder and I try to provide those jar details in pom.xml , but looks like its not referring

jar location - src/main/resources/lib/apache-commons-lang.jar

Here is my maven code :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>apache-commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lib/apache- 
             commons-lang.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

I cant see that mapped in my project properties M2_REPO
can anyone help ?

Comment: Please note that `<systemPath>` should be avoided and Maven repositories should be used instead.

Comment: but I have my jar file in my project itself then how do I need to specify that in  POM.xml ?

Comment: You install it in your Maven local repository, and then reference it as usual without system Path.

Comment: As already mentioned by @JFMeier apart from that you should start to use a repository manager ....

Comment: @JFabianMeier I have no clue how to do that. Any tips?